# Bootstrap search box and button aligned to right of header text (not in nav bar)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and am having difficulty getting the search box and button to drop underneath the heading text when viewed on small screen.

I'd like to get it to stack as follows:

Large screen (as it is currently):

```
[Title] [search input] [submit button]
```

Smaller screen:

```
[Title]
[search input] [submit button]
```

Small screen:

```
[Title]
[search input]
[submit button]
```

Any help much appreciated. I've been at this for ages and my CSS skills are too lacking for me to make any decent headway. Thanks.

Large screen:

[image]

Smaller screen (button gets cut off):

[image]

Small screen:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
         <!-- all the navigation stuff -->
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- main content -->
<div class="container" role="main">

    <div class="page-header">

        <form action="" method="GET" class="form-inline pull-right">

            <div class="form-group form-group-lg has-feedback">

                <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search">

                <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-xl glyphicons-group form-control-feedback"></span>

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
            <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>Search
            </button>

        </form>

        <h2>Quite Long Header Text</h2>

    </div>

<!--rest of page content -->

</div>
```

## update

Thank you @ Robert C. This is how things look with your suggestion:

[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

The button has reduced in size which is great, but the input field now spans the entire width. I think it would all work just fine if the small button and input field were in the same row. This would mean that even on small devices I'd only need two stacks.

Could you suggest how I might go about reducing the size of the input box so that it will allow the button to stick to its left side on the same 'row'?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are using `.container` to house these, why are you not relying on `.row` and .`.col-*-*` to achieve your grid?

Comment: Been playing with various combinations of `col-*-*` for ages and nothing quite works for me. Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add some wrappers to make sure everything is lined up (or, alternatively remove the padding on your `<h2>`) but something along the following should provide you a Bootstrap Grid solution:

```
<div class="container" role="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <h2>Quite Long Header Text</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

            <form action="" method="GET" class="form-main">

            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-search" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-addon group-icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"> Search </span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>      

    </div>
</div>
```

You can see a Bootply fiddle here: http://www.bootply.com/bhvdBwcX4b

To view the Bootply fiddle on smaller screens be sure to click the mobile icon, as simply resizing your browser will result in a rendering error warning.

Comment: Have posted an update using your code - if you could take a peek,  would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just put the button in the same `.col` as the form (and remove the button's separate column altogether).

Comment: Thank Robert. I did that and the button remains stuck to the bottom of the input field. I've updated it here [link](http://www.bootply.com/bhvdBwcX4b). Ah, Bootply didn't keep my changes. Anyway, I just added the button to end of form div, and removed button div entirely.

Comment: You can see an adjusted Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/BWF60KNJaI  Most of this is basic Bootstrap Grid layout; if you're unfamiliar with this you may benefit more from reviewing their documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: Basic questions are allowed here, and yes I have read the docs, but just struggled to make headway. Anyway, answer awarded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head you need to use col and rows to work it out. Here is the col part...

```
<!-- main content -->

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sml-12">
  <h2>Quite Long Header Text</h2>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sml-12">

  <form action="" method="GET" class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group form-group-lg has-feedback">

      <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search">

      <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-xl glyphicons-group form-control-feedback"></span>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
      <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>Search
    </button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have restructured my previous solution for your problem. Have a look at the example here [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/dXEWGq?editors=1100).

Hope it will be helpful to you

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container">
    <!-- all the navigation stuff -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- main content -->
<div class="section-main">
  <div class="container" role="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h2>Quite Long Header Text</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <form action="" method="GET" class="form-main  form-inline nofloat-xs pull-right pull-left-sm">

          <div class="form-group form-input-fields form-group-lg has-feedback">

            <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-search" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search">
              <span class="input-group-addon group-icon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
              </span>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search 
            </button>


          </div>


        </form>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--rest of page content -->

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-main {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.form-input-fields {
 margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.section-main {
  margin-top:40px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.group-icon {
  background-color:#fff;
  border:0; 
}
.input-search {
  border:1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:none;  
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .pull-left-sm {
        float: left !important;
    }

}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nofloat-xs {
        float: none !important;
    }
  .btn-submit {
    margin-top:10px;
  }
}
```

enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I need to have as much vertical space available for the main content so cannot afford to have a search input that spans the entire page. Needs to be:

Large screen (as it is currently):
`[Title] [search input] [submit button](row1)`

Smaller screen:
`[Title] (row1)
[search input] [submit button](row2)`

Small screen:
`[Title] (row1)
[search input](row2)
[submit button](row3)`

Comment: Please check the updated code [Link](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/dXEWGq?editors=1100) as i have edited my above solution also..